# Linq query error in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Logs table created in Windows Azure (WADLogsTable). I need to get a specific column of a given time period. Below is the Linq query I used. Here "Logs" means my own created DTO class. There is no error when building. But when running it gives an error (doesn't show much details).

```
List<Logs> promotionInfo =null;

promotionInfo = (from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<Logs>("WADLogsTable")
                         where e.Timestamp > startDate && e.Timestamp < endDate
                         select new Logs { Pid= e.Pid }).ToList();
```

Please show me where is my fault.

Comment: "an error" isn't helpful - what *does* it say? You say it doesn't show much details, but presumably it says more than "an error" ?

Comment: Tim, Please edit your post to be as specific as possible about your question and any errors that your code gives.

Answer (score 3):

Since there isn't much information to go by... engaging google-fu...

There is a [known feature](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/66f45e74-ceed-4329-b4ae-8351545e8f22/) in `CreateQuery<T>` where-by  it can error if there are no results (especially if the table is empty) and there are multiple  "where" conditions (which goes in via a different type of operation). The linked page shows a workaround to this, which basically involves setting `IgnoreResourceNotFoundException` to true.